# Hbase 0.94.14 with hadoop 1.2 gives an error

Tags: hadoop, hbase

The logs output

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PBUF\00
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKTableReadOnly.getTableState(ZKTableReadOnly.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKTable.getTableState(ZKTable.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKTable.populateTableStates(ZKTable.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKTable.<init>(ZKTable.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.<init>(AssignmentManager.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.initializeZKBasedSystemTrackers(HMaster.java:505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:432)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

hbase-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/diptesh/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

This is hadoop on pseudo distributed mode and for some reason hbase will not start.

Comment: Please add the action performed, and result obtained.

Comment: This was while trying to start hbase (0.94.14) with hadoop 1.2 (pseudo distributed). This is the output of the logs. I'll post my hbase-site.xml